# Pre loading templates and template variables before parsing in Django

Tags: python, django, templates

I have a txt file I load in views.py and do some work on (right now it's just splitting by paragraph, but later there will be more work done).

Within this document, I have some of Django template tags {{ user.firstName }}, etc.

I send this document to the template to get its HTML added, etc.  But it won't render the tags.  I do know that Django loads the template once and stores it all within a tree for speed.  I just can't find a workaround.  Can I pre-load the document, then have the parser run?  Could I add the HTML tags within the view.py and send it to the template before parsing?

Any ideas or thoughts would be great.

Here is what I have for code:

View.py

```
class DocumentReview(TemplateView):
template_name = 'paperwork\document.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(DocumentReview, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['user'] = {'firstName': 'x', 'lastName': 'y'}
    context['document'] = self.get_document()
    return context


def get_document(self):
    module_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)  # get current directory
    file_path = os.path.join(module_dir, 'documents\sample.txt')
    document = {}
    with open(file_path, 'r') as fp:
        data = fp.read()
        document = data.split("\n\n")
    return document
```

Here is sample.txt:

```
Hello {{ user.firstName }} {{ user.lastName }},

 This is a sample txt file.
```

And this is the document.html

```
      {% for para in document %}
                <p>{{ para }}</p>
                {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the [template loader](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/templates/#usage) module, and change your `get_document` function:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string 
def get_document(self, context):
    data = render_to_string('documents\sample.txt', context)
    return data.split("\n\n")
```

And you call it this way:

```
context['document'] = self.get_document(context)
```

Before that, you have to modify your `settings.TEMPLATES` in order for the loader to find your file `documents\sample.txt`.